# what is Valgrind error overlap in strcpy?

Tags: c, valgrind

I am facing this error I never have faced using valgrind do you guys have any input. I am new to C and still learning. Thank you!

This is below the error I got using valgrind.

```
==8410== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0xfff000560, 0xfff000560)
==8410==    at 0x4C2E272: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8410==    by 0x40126B: trim (in /********/********/********/private/********/********/********/calls)
==8410==    by 0x40154B: main (in /********/********/********/private/********/********/********/calls)
==8410==
==8410== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0xfff000560, 0xfff000560)
==8410==    at 0x4C2E272: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8410==    by 0x40126B: trim (in /********/********/********/private/********/********/********/calls)
==8410==    by 0x4016C6: main (in /********/********/********/private/********/********/********/calls)
==8410==
==8410==
==8410== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8410==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8410==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 30 frees, 1,288 bytes allocated
==8410==
==8410== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8410== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8410== ERROR SUMMARY: 19 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

my method

```
static char *trim(char *s)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); i++)    // skip leading
        ;
    int from = i;    // start here
    
    for (; s[i]; i++)    // move until end
        ;

    // move backwards, skip trailing
    for (i--; i>from && isspace(s[i]); i--)
        ;
    s[i+1] = '\0';    // stop here

    strcpy(s, &s[from]);    // copy this part to beginning
          
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Well, `s` and `s[from]` are obviously overlapping. This is not allowed. This is explicitly stated in `strcpy` documentation.

Comment: @Leo Use memmove instead of strcpy.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow will it do the same job as copying?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am getting too few arguments changing to memmove

Comment: You have a comment `// (it is ok as we copy from higher to upper addresses always)` — that is incorrect.  If the source and destination strings overlap, the behaviour is undefined and that's what Valgrind is telling you.  Using `memmove()`, you have to say how many characters to copy — that's the third argument you're missing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see thank you

Comment: @Leo: You should revert the edit, since it's covering up the error that was the source of your question to begin with. Edits are not to revise your code once you fix it, but to revise the question if the original was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this line

```
strcpy(s, &s[from]);
```

To

```
                    //# of characters
memmove(s, &s[from], i - from + 1);
```

Comment: I think I'd expect to see `memmove(s, &s[from], strlen(&s[from]) + 1);` so that the length is calculated correctly and the terminal null byte is copied too (`strlen()` doesn't count the terminal null byte).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh thank you I wasn't sure about that

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that would be more dynamic than what I have put as well right?

Comment: Yes: it would work correctly for different lengths of strings, neither overrunning short strings nor omitting key portions of long strings.  Note that `memcpy()` has a 'no overlap' restriction; only `memmove()` works correctly for overlapping data.

Comment: You don't need `strlen`. You already calculated that using `i`.

Comment: @ZanLynx — you read the rest of the code; I just looked at what it would take to get `memmove()` to work correctly.  I see that `i = strlren(&s[from]);` is written out in a loop in the function (`for (;s[i];i++);`).  But `i` is then decremented as trailing white space is removed too.  I think you'd need to use `i - from + 1` as the length; there could still be an off-by-one error here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It just bugs me to call a function to get a value the code is already holding... It would be something like `(i - from + 1)` I think.

Comment: Yes, I agree — the value needed is already available (and I didn't notice that when scanning).  Two brilliant people both coming up with `i - from + 1` suggests that might be correct :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As Knuth wrote somewhere, paraphrased, I wrote this code but I didn't test it. Heh.

Comment: so its best to use `i - from + 1` ?

Comment: In this context, we think (but haven't formally verified) that using `i - from + 1` in place of `strlen(&s[from]) + 1` would be correct and (marginally) quicker than calling `strlen()`.  Double-check by experimenting.  If you're dealing with a 20 kilobyte string with a couple of kilobytes of trailing white space, the results might be different from what you get from dealing with a 20 byte string.

Comment: So far I have tested 4 test cases with 4 different file inputs all worked with `i - from + 1` with no errors or any other issues

Comment: Wikiquotes on [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) says: _Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it._ It's even the first item in the list of quotes, @ZanLynx.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it explained *why* the suggested change is necessary.